# How to convert a data frame to a 3d array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a data frame that I want to convert to a three-dimensional array. One of the columns in the data frame should serve as the grouping variable for splitting the frame into 2d matrices that can be combined into the array. In the following minimal working example, the data frame should be split into matrices by the variable "i", then combined into a 4x4x2 array. The solution should be practical for large data sets and ideally could be generalized to convert a data frame into a n dimensional array.

```
# Make reproducible 
set.seed(123)

df <- {
  data.frame(i=rep(1:2, each=4),
             x=rep(rep(0:1, each=2), 2),
             y=rep(rep(0:1, 2), 2),
             l=rnorm(8))
}

df
#   i x y           l
# 1 1 0 0 -0.56047565
# 2 1 0 1 -0.23017749
# 3 1 1 0  1.55870831
# 4 1 1 1  0.07050839
# 5 2 0 0  0.12928774
# 6 2 0 1  1.71506499
# 7 2 1 0  0.46091621
# 8 2 1 1 -1.26506123
```

Note: I suspect that Hadley Wickham's plyr may provide the needed tool, perhaps daply?

Comment: Are you just looking for `split(df, df$i)`?

Comment: I was looking for abind(split(df, df$i), along=3). You were half way there.

Comment: Posted another alternative, just for variety.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I'd probably do:

```
library(abind)
abind(split(df, df$i), along=3)
# , , 1
# 
#   i x y           l
# 5 1 0 0 -0.56047565
# 6 1 0 1 -0.23017749
# 7 1 1 0  1.55870831
# 8 1 1 1  0.07050839
# 
# , , 2
# 
#   i x y          l
# 5 2 0 0  0.1292877
# 6 2 0 1  1.7150650
# 7 2 1 0  0.4609162
# 8 2 1 1 -1.2650612
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you are looking for `split`:

```
> split(df, df$i)
$`1`
  i x y           l
1 1 0 0 -0.56047565
2 1 0 1 -0.23017749
3 1 1 0  1.55870831
4 1 1 1  0.07050839

$`2`
  i x y          l
5 2 0 0  0.1292877
6 2 0 1  1.7150650
7 2 1 0  0.4609162
8 2 1 1 -1.2650612
```

This results in a `list` of two `data.frame`s separated by your "i" column.

---

To get an `array`, you've got Josh's answer, or you can use `simplify2array` from base R:

```
> simplify2array(by(df, df$i, as.matrix))
, , 1

  i x y           l
1 1 0 0 -0.56047565
2 1 0 1 -0.23017749
3 1 1 0  1.55870831
4 1 1 1  0.07050839

, , 2

  i x y          l
1 2 0 0  0.1292877
2 2 0 1  1.7150650
3 2 1 0  0.4609162
4 2 1 1 -1.2650612
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm reading the question wrong, but the MWE describes a 2x2x2 array (x, y, i (a.k.a. z)). The current answers appear to provide solutions that provide arrays of data.frames rather than arrays of 2D matrices (per OP). `array()` will convert a `data.frame` to an array of n-dimensional matrices:

```
dfa <- array(data = df$l, 
             dim=c(length(unique(df$x)), 
                   length(unique(df$y)), 
                   length(unique(df$i))), 
             dimnames=list(unique(df$x), unique(df$y), unique(df$i))
            )
dfa
> dfa
, , 1

           0          1
0 -0.5604756 1.55870831
1 -0.2301775 0.07050839

, , 2

          0          1
0 0.1292877  0.4609162
1 1.7150650 -1.2650612
```

Comment: Good point @Brian D. The answers above aren't really matrices.

Comment: plus 1: Bravo for this solution which answers the OP more precisely.