# Reshape dataframe to multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a data frame that has a xyz and another variable, A.

```
data.frame(xx,yy,zz,Amp)
           xx       yy           zz   Amp
1    63021.71 403205.0  1.181028516  1170
2    63021.71 403105.0  0.977028516  1381
3    63021.71 403105.0  0.861028516   807
4    63021.71 403105.0  0.784028516   668
5    53021.71 403105.0  0.620028516 19919
6    53021.71 403305.0  0.455028516 32500
7    53021.71 403105.0  0.446028516 32500
8    43021.71 403105.0  0.436028516 32500
9    43021.71 404105.0  0.426028516 32500
10   43021.71 403105.0  0.281028516 17464
```

First I want to create regular grid for `xyz`.

Next I want to fill this grid with `Amp` values. 
I would like to do this by creating by using arrays.
Any help would be much appreciated.

i would like the final result to look like this:

```
dim(Amp)
10 10 10
```

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: I think you're looking for something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533492/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-a-3d-array-in-r).

Comment: I edit the question to what I expect from the output

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough data in your MWE to create a 10x10x10 array without interpolation.  Currently you have 3 unique xx values, 4 unique yy values, and 10 unique zz values. So you could create a 3x4x10 array, but you don't have enough values in Amp to assign to each point in a 3x4x10 3D regular grid. You only have 10 Amp values, describing 10 unique points in 3D space. A 3x4x10 regular grid array would have 120 Amp values, one for each point in the grid. Furthermore, values in a *regular* grid are equally spaced in each dimension and your yy and zz values are not equally spaced.

Check the spacing in each dimension:

```
> diff(sort(unique(xx)))
[1] 10000 10000

> diff(sort(unique(yy)))
[1] 100 100 800

> diff(sort(unique(zz)))
[1] 0.145 0.010 0.010 0.009 0.165 0.164 0.077 0.116 0.204
```

The current MWE looks like this in 3D:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(xx,yy,zz, col="red")
```

[image: 3D plot of OP example data]

To form a 10x10x10 regular grid, you need to convert your dataset into one that has 1000 coordinate points and Amp values. I'm not exactly sure how you'd like to do this given your MWE, but here's an example given the current data:

```
# MWE data
xx = c(63021.71,63021.71,63021.71,63021.71,53021.71,53021.71,53021.71,43021.71,43021.71,43021.71)
yy = c(403205,403105,403105,403105,403105,403305,403105,403105,404105,403105)
zz = c(1.181028516,0.977028516,0.861028516,0.784028516,0.620028516,0.455028516,0.446028516,0.436028516,0.426028516,0.281028516)
Amp = c(1170,1381,807,668,19919,32500,32500,32500,32500,17464)

# create equally-spaced vectors of 10 values in each dimension
xx <- seq(min(xx), max(xx), length.out = 10)
yy <- seq(min(yy), max(yy), length.out = 10)
zz <- seq(min(zz), max(zz), length.out = 10)

# fake up some Amp data points
set.seed(123)
Amp <- runif(1000, min = min(Amp), max=max(Amp))

# directly create a 10x10x10 regular grid of Amp values as an array
dfa <- array(data = Amp, 
             dim = c(10,10,10), 
             dimnames = list(xx,yy,zz)
)
> dim(dfa)
[1] 10 10 10

# Alternatively, make a data.frame first
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(xx,yy,zz))
names(df) <- c("xx","yy","zz")
df$Amp <- Amp  

dfa <- array(data = df$Amp, 
             dim=c(length(unique(df$xx)), 
                   length(unique(df$yy)), 
                   length(unique(df$zz))), 
             dimnames=list(unique(df$xx), unique(df$yy), unique(df$zz))
)

# you'll want to verify that the Amp values were assigned to the correct xyz coordinates. 
# Here's a little function to help:
get_arr_loc = function(x, y, z) {
  x + (y-1)*10 + (z-1)*100
}

# and some arbitrary coordinates checked. This could be done in a more systematic way...    
> df[get_arr_loc(1,1,1), "Amp"] == dfa[1,1,1]
[1] TRUE
> df[get_arr_loc(10,2,1), "Amp"] == dfa[10,2,1]
[1] TRUE
> df[get_arr_loc(3,6,9), "Amp"] == dfa[3,6,9]
[1] TRUE
> df[get_arr_loc(10,10,10), "Amp"] == dfa[10,10,10]
[1] TRUE
```