# R: Transform dataframe into three dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I would like to transform a data frame e.g.

```
day <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
area <-c("A","B","C")
area <- rep(area,3)
measure1 <- c(99,97,95,102,105,98,103,98,90)
measure2 <- c(3,4,78,2,5,9,7,4,3)
A_dataframe <-data.frame(
  day,area,measure1,measure2
)
```

into three dimensional arrays where the first dimension is Area: "A", "B", "C" while 2nd and 3rd dimensions containing day as row and measure1&measure2 as column corresponding to its area "A", "B" or "C"?

I am familiar with cell array in Matlab so wondering if R can perform something similar.

I have tried "melt" and "dcast" but none is successful.

Appreciated.

Comment: So something like `simplify2array(by(A_dataframe, A_dataframe$area, as.matrix))` ?  from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533492/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-a-3d-array-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_split()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df_to_list <- A_dataframe %>% 
  dplyr::group_split(area)

names(df_to_list) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

However, I am not quite sure what you mean by "3rd dimension" exactly.

Comment: you don't need to `group_by(area)`. `A_dataframe %>%   group_split(area)`