# Nested Loop in R for creating arrays of matrices

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

With the following data set, I would like to make an array of 3(three columns in T, T1,T2 and T3) matrices of order 2( no of rows) by 11(length of fu.time).

```
b0=data.frame(b0_1=c(11.41,11.36),b0_2=c(8.767,6.950))
b1=data.frame(b1_1=c(0.8539,0.9565),b1_2=c(-0.03179,0.06752))
b2=data.frame(b2_1=c(-0.013020 ,-0.016540),b2_2=c(-0.0002822,-0.0026720))
T.val=data.frame(T1=c(1,1),T2=c(1,2),T3=c(2,1))
d_data=cbind(b0,b1,b2,T.val)
fu.time=seq(0,1,by=0.1)
pat=ncol(T.val)
nit=2
```

I tried the follwoing loop, Unfortunately it is not working.

```
pt.array=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat))  

for ( it.er in 1:nit){
  for ( ti in 1:length(new.time_2q.RI)){
    for (pt in 1:pat){
      pt.array[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2
    }
  }
}
```

The concept is, if `T1` takes value `1`, then the first column of `b0,b1 and b2` are taken. If any of the `T` takes value `2` then the corresponding second column value of `b0,b1, and b2` are taken.

Comment: Can you show what values would your expected output have?

Comment: Loops may not be needed. See [How to convert a data frame to a 3d array in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533492/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-a-3d-array-in-r) and [Transform dataframe into three dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288114/r-transform-dataframe-into-three-dimensional-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @RonakShah see the answer, It is working now. Alternative approaches are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following nested loop is working.

```
 pt.array1=array(NA, dim=c(nit,length(fu.time),pat)) 

    for ( it.er in 1:nit){
      for ( ti in 1:length(fu.time)){
        for (pt in 1:pat){
          pt.array1[it.er,ti,pt]=b0[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]+b1[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]+b2[it.er,T.val[it.er,pt]]*fu.time[ti]^2
        }
      }
    }
```

Alternative approaches are appreciated if any.