# Create 4 dimensions array from dataframe R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

I would like to use a dataframe to create a 4D array in R.
The dataframe has a column for the ids, one for the months, one for the years and one for the values I am working with.
I would like to structure the arrays with rows with ids, the columns for the variable and in the third dimension of the array the values for each month, and in the fourth the years.
So:
dimensions num_ids * num_variables * num_months * num_years

```
ids <- c(1:8)
months <- c('10','11','12','01','02','10','11','12')
years <- c('2019','2020','2021','2022','2019','2020','2021','2022')
km <- c(3456, 54654, 76765, 57676, 8689, 87989, 8632, 42325)
df <- cbind(ids, months, years, km)
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I have multiple dataset for each variables with the same structure reported here, in this example km is the variable

Comment: which column are the values? or are you just doing some counting?

Comment: km in this case, I have a dataset for each variable with the same structure reported here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current form, your data can't be made into even a 2D matrix (e.g. `id` x `year`) without a bunch of missing values, and many of the R approaches for creating arrays will recycle your existing values to make up for those that are missing. So the following command would give you what you want if (and only if) your starting `df` was complete:

```
with(df, array(data=km, dim=c(length(unique(ids)),
                        length(unique(months)),
                        length(unique(years))),
      dimnames=list(unique(ids), unique(months), unique(years))))
```

But we can also call the tidyverse `pivot` functions to "cheat" and fill in `NA` where your starting data are missing (we have to do it twice, once for `year` and once for `month`), and then we can make a 3D array (mostly comprised of `NA` values). If you add a fourth variable to your data, you could do the `pivot` trick again, and use `array` to cast the whole thing into a 4D array.

```
library(tidyverse)
# "pivot_wider" will fill in any missing values with NA, "pivot_longer" returns to
#   original shape
df_1 <- pivot_wider(df, names_from=years, values_from=km) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols='2019':'2022', names_to='years', values_to='km')
df_2 <- pivot_wider(df_1, names_from=months, values_from=km) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols='10':'02', names_to='months', values_to='km')
# to get "array" call to operate properly, have to sort data (with "arrange") such that
#   the "fastest-moving" variable (in this case, months) is first, followed by the 
#   next-fastest, etc.
df_3 <- with(arrange(df_2, months, years, ids), 
             array(data=km, dim=c(length(unique(ids)),
                                  length(unique(years)),
                                  length(unique(months))),
                   dimnames=list(unique(ids), unique(years), unique(months))))
df_3[1, '2019', '10']  # will return 3456
df_3[4, '2022', '01']  # will return 57676
df_3[1, '2019', '11']  # will return NA
```

(Approach inspired by last answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533492/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-a-3d-array-in-r).)

Comment: Thank you so much, this works for one variable, in case I have two df for two variables and I would like to use put the two variable as columns in a 4-d array?

Comment: I’m not totally sure, because I don’t really know how you want to combine your two dfs, but my advice is that it is always best to start by putting all your data into a tidy (aka long, aka narrow) format, similar to what your example started with, where there is one measurement (`km`) per row and as many descriptor variables as you want in columns. From there you can use my method to melt it into an array of whatever dimensions you want - although, for most applications, I don’t think arrays are actually very useful.